# jQuery addClass page A, and next page B history back() keep addClass A

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with jQuery.

Example code:

```js
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
   $("p:first").addClass("intro");
  });
 });
</script>
```

Visitor on page A, click to button. "p" add class intro, and then visitor click to page B. 
Visitor on page B click `history.goback()`.
When goback to page A, "p" does not have class "intro".
How can I make "p" have class "intro" when visitor goback without click to "button"?

Comment: well you would have to code something that remembers that they clicked the button. On page load you check that cookie or localstorage value and if it is set, than set the class.

Comment: Can you help edit my example code to can do it? I am a newbie. Thank you a lot.

Comment: You need to push that state into the browsers history: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API (or replace the current state)

Answer (score 0):

You can check by entering a new page by reacting to the onready-event. In the onload event you check if the page you load is PageA or B and set the styles depending on the value. The `location.href` returns the current url. Or if you need to hold the state then you can have usage of localStorage which, can store key values.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         var href = location.href;
         if(location.indexOf("pageA")){
         $("p:first").addClass("intro");
         }
     });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i have a lot of like "pageA" without Class or ID. I have a button. When visitor on a page click to "button" and "p:first" addClass "intro", then visitor click to page another and then visitor click  history.goback(). i want previous page keep "p.frist" with class "intro". Please help me exactly my example. Because i am a newbie. Thanks again.